# What is the best way to crawl a login based sites?

Tags: c#, python, watin, web-crawler, html-parsing

I've to automate a file download activity from a website (similar to, let's say, yahoomail.com). To reach a page which has this file download link, i've to login, jump from page to page to provide some parameters like dates etc., and finally click on download link.

I am thinking of three approaches:

1. Using WatIN and develop a windows service that periodically executes some WatiN code to traverse through the page and download the file.
2. Using AutoIT (no much idea)
3. Using a simple HTML parsing technique (there are several questions here eg., how to maintain a session after doing a login? how to do a logout after doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) script, automated with [Selenium Remote Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/).

Answer (score 5):

I use [scrapy.org](http://scrapy.org), it's a python library. It's quiet good actually. Easy to write spiders and it's very extensive in it's functionality. Scraping sites after login is available in the package.

Here is an example of a spider that would crawl a site after authentication.

```
class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    domain_name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                callback=self.after_login)]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

Comment: What happens the url is emiting javascript like document.writeln to fill the browser document? Is Scrapy works in this case?

Comment: There are 2 scenarios that I can think of

Comment: 1. All of the data is in the page when the page loads, but it's in js instead of html(this is pretty unlikely). But if this is the case, then I believe you can parse it and scrapy has some functionality for as vaguely indicated here: http://doc.scrapy.org/intro/overview.html?highlight=javascript#what-else

Comment: 2. Data is loaded with ajax. This is a lot more likely. In this case, you can figure out what requests are made to query the data and simulate those requests directly without js.

Answer (score 3):

I used [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) for Python with success for a few things.  It's easy to use and supports HTTP authentication, form handling, cookies, automatic HTTP redirection (30X), ...  Basically the only thing missing is JavaScript, but if you need to rely on JS you're pretty much screwed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) is great for crawling, and you could use [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).